# kubernetes - failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, configmap

I have a prometheus container running in k8s and is using longhorn as storage to store config files and DB. The Prometheus container starts successfully and could be accessed by Prometheus UI as well for around 2-3 mins and crashes immediately. When I describe the k8s pod, it shows below error message during crash.

"MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "prometheus-config-volume" : failed to sync configmap cache: timed out waiting for the condition"

The configmap being referred by prometheus-config-volume does exist. So, I am not sure what is going wrong here as prometheus logs too didn't have any helpful message for. Could someone help me find the issue here?

Regards,
Nanda

Comment: Hi, can you share with us more details about the platform and the kubernetes cluster versions? This kind of error can be related to node resources overutilization leading to timesout.